# Chrome and Firefox lose ability to use keyboard on Fedora 38 while other applications can use keyboard

Tags: linux, google-chrome, usb, keyboard, fedora

We have a number of Fedora 38 systems where sporadically Chrome and Firefox no longer receive keyboard input. Other applications, like terminal, do not experience this issue. Chrome is not locked as it responds to mouse events and event the console is unable to receive keyboard inputs.

The only solution so far has been to restart the system. What could be the cause and what are some possible troubleshooting steps ?

Comment: What versions of Chrome and FFox? Have you updated to the latest Firefox using dnf https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#upgrade-command-label

Comment: I've noticed the same occasionally (and very rarely) in other Linux distros (Ubuntu and Deepin) and I was never able to get to bottom of it.